# Save a text file as a String in C

Tags: c, windows, command, command-prompt

I want to save a text file as a String and then print it. Here's my code:

```
int lastLines(const char nameFileIn[], int nLines) {
    char *text = 0;
    FILE *inF;  long length;
    inF = fopen(nameFileIn, "r");
    if (inF == NULL)
        return -1;
    fseek(inF, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell(inF);
    fseek(inF, 0, SEEK_SET);
    text = malloc(length + 1);
    fread(text, length + 1, 1, inF); 
    fclose(inF);    
    text[length] = 0;   
    printf("%s", text);
    free(text);
    return 0; } /* lastLines */

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char* nameFileIn = (argv[1]);
    int nLines = atoi((argv[2]));   
    int num = lastLines(nameFileIn, nLines);        
    printf("\n%d\n", num);
    
    return 1; } /* main */
```

Everything is alright 'till I add the second parameter in the command line (I'll need it in a postprocessing phase). At that time in my String there are a number of characters (equals to the number of lines in my file) which are not in my text file. Why?

Comment: The function does not do anything with `int nLines` argument. Having read all the file, you could search through it and count the newlines, then truncate the string at that point, instead of at the end of the buffer.

Comment: Who is teaching you to use `fseek()`/`ftell()` to get the size of a file?  [It's *wrong*, especially on Windows](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.4p2): "For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified information, usable by the fseek function for returning the file position indicator for the stream to its position at the time of the ftell call; **the difference between two such return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read**."

Comment: Because in Windows, the CR-LF character pair is converted to *one* newline character on input, (conversely on output) and `fseek` has no way of determining this in advance.